# Can't map Oracle stored procedure in entity framework 6

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6 database-first with an Oracle 11g database. I have a stored procedure that looks something like this:

```
PROCEDURE get_user (p_usr_id IN usr.usr_id%TYPE, rc_usr OUT ct_usr)
IS
BEGIN
 OPEN rc_usr FOR
    SELECT usr_id, email_address
    FROM   usr
    WHERE  usr_id = p_usr_id;
END;
```

First, I open the edmx, right click > "Update Model From Database", and import the stored procedure. Then in the model browser, I right click the stored procedure and click "Add Function Import". In the option "Returns a Collection of" I choose none. I go back to the model browser and find the stored procedure under "Function Imports".

But when I expand the function import, it only shows P_USR_ID as a parameter. How do I pass in the ref_cursor so I can retrieve the results?

NOTE: I cannot change the stored procedure.